# Adding @EnableWebMvc in Springboot changes date output from string to array

Tags: java, spring-boot

I Cretae one springboot(2.0.6.RELEASE) and put in my application.yml the configuration:

```
jackson:
    date-format: dd/MM/yyyy
```

so when my user call my API every date return just like this:

```
"vencimento": "01/07/2017"
```

so, now I put an CORS in my project

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

but now, all my date filed return just like this:

```
"vencimento": [
            2017,
            1,
            7
        ],
```

anyone know why? and how to fix this? tks

Comment: Are you sure the issue is caused by the CORS? Did you change something else?

Comment: Seems odd that Cors configuration would cause this problem. What's your controller look like?

Comment: @CROSP i remove the CORS return to "vencimento": "01/07/2017"

Comment: the problem was the @EnableWebMvc anyone know why? tks

Comment: @FabioEbner,  if you use `@EnableWebMvc` in a Spring Boot app you switch off the default settings in the framework, so maybe you should avoid that.

Comment: @CROSP a question I only use to create RESTAPI so I don`t need to use @EnableWebMvc correct? tks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With adding @EnableWebMvc [you're saying to Spring that you want to get the full control over Spring MVC configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration). So you need to configure the Jackson object mapper manually.

The main thing is to add these settings:

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

By default, `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` is enabled, and it gives an array of date-time components similar to yours (f.e., `[2014,3,30,12,30,23,123456789]` instead of `"2014-03-30T12:30:23.123456789"`).

The example of how to configure object mapper and register it as bean in @Configuration class (if you don't familiar with how to do it):

```
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        jsonMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

        //some other configuration like:
        jsonMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        jsonMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);

        return jsonMapper;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

As [CROSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932574/adding-enablewebmvc-in-springboot-changes-date-output-from-string-to-array#comment96630810_54932574) said that enabling `@EnableWebMvc` will turn off default settings in Spring Boot. Here is how I config CORS without using `@EnableWebMvc` annotation:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class CorsConfig {

  @Bean
  fun corsConfigurer() = object : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
      registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*")
      super.addCorsMappings(registry)
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/#global-cors-configuration)